# Button Click event won't fire in WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a layout like this.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="gridTestAd" Height="80" Margin="-12,0,-12,0" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Tap="StackPanel_Tap">
                        <StackPanel.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/image.jpg" />
                        </StackPanel.Background>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <adduplex:AdControl x:Name="adDuplexAd" AppId="123456"/>
                    <Button Name="btnRemoveAd" Content="X" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Red" Foreground="White" Template="{StaticResource RemoveAdsButtonStyle}" Margin="0,-20,6,0" Click="btnRemoveAd_Click" />
</Grid>
```

I have set a breakpointin the btnRemoveAd_Click event but when i tap the button, the click event will not fire. Originally i created a custom button using images but that did not work either. This button is slightly edited using Blend because its so small and content is not showing. But only changes to Margin of the original button. I have search for the reasons but did not find any and i cant figure it either. What may be the problem? Please help

Control Template for the button

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="RemoveAdsButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualTransition From="Normal" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.25" To="Pressed">
                            <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                            </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        </VisualTransition>
                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle1" StrokeThickness="0">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/img/close_small.png"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" StrokeThickness="0" Opacity="0">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Assets/img/close_small_presses.png"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: It's possible that another control overlaps with the button and captures the event. Does it work if you remove the StackPanel and the AdControl?

Comment: I think some control which is after the the grid is overlaping the button in transparent. can you check them buy setting background colors to the other controls outside the grid.

Comment: i have checked, nothing overlaps. i have grid rows assigned for every element and i can tap on the button. it has animation to indicate that. So definitely the button gets the tap. And i have tried out side the grid. Same thing. but, if i add  button without any styling it works.

Comment: The reason seems to be the style. You should post it for further help

Comment: Added the control template created for the button.

Comment: Your template has no problem. You should test the button separately then gradually add other controls to find the cause.

Comment: Its odd to say the least, i made few buttons in the same way in another project it works fine. @DavidTo thanks for the suggestion. i'll try it out

Comment: I am having a similar issue. The button tapped events occur only if I make my buttons huge on the canvas. Was your problem ever resolved?

Comment: The cause of my problem was that i was using the button on top of the AdDuplex ad controller. They don;t allow it. They detect if any elements obstruct the adController and that will generate problems. That's why when ever i place my button anywhere it worked.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I stripped out all the XAML and just had a button defined. in an app bar. I then created a new page and put a button in that page.. Still not firing! This has to be a bug.